# Is it possible to change the color of "vt.handoff" screen at boot?

Tags: boot, customization

Just curious, is there a configfile to change the purple bootscreen that appears between grub and plymouth? I know how to change plymouth's background color, but it does not affect the screen for `vt.handoff`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Open a gnome-terminal.
- Run the following:

  ```
  gksu gedit /lib/plymouth/themes/default.grub
  ```
- Replace `44,0,30` with `0,0,0` (or any other color of form `R,G,B` with R, G, and B being between 0 and 255).
- Save, close, and run `sudo update-grub` in the terminal.
- Reboot and enjoy.